# Sqlconnection still requires ssl but "encrypt=false"

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ssl

I've an application written in C# (framework 4.6) that uses `System.Data.SqlClient` to communicate with a SQL Server 2014. This application does NOT use SSL to connect to SQL.

The connection to SQL Server fails with this error:

> a connection was established but ... protocol error ... opening
>   session (SSL provider error 0)

On the server, I observe in the events: Schannel errors 36874 and 36888 (A TLS1.2 connection request was received from a remote client application, but none of the cipher suites supported by the client application are supported by the server. )

I've tried to force `encrypt=false` in the connect string to disable any SSL option, but this does not solve the problem.

This error does not occur on all computers of the same network.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Kind regards,

Guy

Comment: The server can force the use of an SSL connection regardless of client settings. Just go through the documentation, and see if any of it applies to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have find a solution for this problem. We need to add news keys on the registry.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client]
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000001
"Enabled"=dword:00000000
```

After restart of computer, problem is solved but we dont understand why somes computer would connect with tls 1.2

Comment: What computer was this applied to, server or client?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check on the registry settings of the computer opening up the connection to SQL server.  There is a little known edit that can force all connections to be TLS 1.2.

[Registry information](http://www.johnlouros.com/blog/enabling-strong-cryptography-for-all-dot-net-applications)

The gist of the fix for us was to check on these settings:

> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
>   "SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
>   "SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001

If you want it enabled, use it as is.  If you want them disabled, you can set the to 0 or delete the keys.

Comment: Thanks for this tip. These keys did not exists. What seem to be correct when secure connection is not desired. By creating the keys with a 0 value, the error remain.